# can't install any new packages

Tags: package-management, ruby

I have been trying to install ruby on rails and I run into failures in all directions. I finally went into the package manager and right away it detected an issue and asked me if I wanted to resolve it. Upon clicking yes, it ran and gave me the below output; failing again.

I think this has something to do with a wine installation from before because I remember getting a vague warning about not being able to upgrade after 'this'.

Can anyone tell me how to repair this short of blasting away the whole system? I spent a lot of time getting it up to speed. I disabled all 3rd party repositories

ruby install logs:

```
christian@christian:~$ gem install rails
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.1.0 directory.
christian@christian:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for christian: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20160303-13069-17ounbe.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
christian@christian:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ruby' instead of 'rubygems'
E: Unable to locate package mysql-devel
E: Unable to locate package ruby-devel
christian@christian:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-dev rubygems
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ruby' instead of 'rubygems'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: cpp (>= 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) but 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 kmod : Depends: libkmod2 (= 22-1ubuntu1) but 21-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 ruby : Depends: ruby2.2 but it is not going to be installed
 ruby-dev : Depends: ruby2.2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
christian@christian:~$ apt-get remove ruby
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
christian@christian:~$ sudo apt-get remove ruby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kmod : Depends: libkmod2 (= 22-1ubuntu1) but 21-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
christian@christian:~$ uname -a
Linux christian 4.2.0-30-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 00:58:07 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

package update logs:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 222876 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.19.0-53-generic (3.19.0-53.59) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.19.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-53-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-53-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-53-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 2.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-53-generic with 2.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-53-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kmod:
 kmod depends on libkmod2 (= 22-1ubuntu1); however:
  Version of libkmod2:amd64 on system is 21-1ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package kmod (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools-core:
 initramfs-tools-core depends on kmod | module-init-tools; however:
  Package kmod is not configured yet.
  Package module-init-tools is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-core (= 0.122ubuntu3); however:
  Package initramfs-tools-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on initramfs-tools | dracut; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
  Package dracut is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-drivers-common:
 ubuntu-drivers-common depends on kmod | module-init-tools; however:
  Package kmod is not configured yet.
```

Comment: Could you please try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and report back what happens. You could also try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any loose no longer needed packages - don't worry that command is safe and will only remove installed packages that no longer have any dependencies nor dependant on anything and possibly broken packages. You can also do `sudo apt-get autoclean` to remove temporary deb files which are downloaded when you install something.

Comment: Answer below did the trick! Very close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post:

https://askubuntu.com/a/647250/505633

It seems to address the same problem.

Comment: It did. Should I delete this question?

Comment: no, you have a different topic. There are many ways to ask a question.